# Transform conllu file in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I'm working on a project in python.
I have to read a CONLLU file (which i did successfully) but I'm not able to transform in the format that I wished.

Within a list, I have to store another list which contains a sentence, in which each word, is contained within a tuple with its UPOS (Universal Part of Speech).

**This is the format that I'd like to obtain:**

`[[('Pierre', 'NOUN'), ('Vinken', 'NOUN'), (',', '.'), ('61', 'NUM'), ('years', 'NOUN'), ('old', 'ADJ'), (',', '.'), ('will', 'VERB'), ('join', 'VERB'), ('the', 'DET'), ('board', 'NOUN'), ('as', 'ADP'), ('a', 'DET'), ('nonexecutive', 'ADJ'), ('director', 'NOUN'), ('Nov.', 'NOUN'), ('29', 'NUM'), ('.', '.')], [('Mr.', 'NOUN'), ('Vinken', 'NOUN'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('chairman', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Elsevier', 'NOUN'), ('N.V.', 'NOUN'), (',', '.'), ('the', 'DET'), ('Dutch', 'NOUN'), ('publishing', 'VERB'), ('group', 'NOUN'), ('.', '.')]]`

**Instead this is what I get**

`[('Pierre', 'NOUN'), ('Vinken', 'NOUN'), (',', '.'), ('61', 'NUM'), ('years', 'NOUN'), ('old', 'ADJ'), (',', '.'), ('will', 'VERB'), ('join', 'VERB'), ('the', 'DET'), ('board', 'NOUN'), ('as', 'ADP'), ('a', 'DET'), ('nonexecutive', 'ADJ'), ('director', 'NOUN'), ('Nov.', 'NOUN'), ('29', 'NUM'), ('.', '.'), ('Mr.', 'NOUN'), ('Vinken', 'NOUN'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('chairman', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Elsevier', 'NOUN'), ('N.V.', 'NOUN'), (',', '.'), ('the', 'DET'), ('Dutch', 'NOUN'), ('publishing', 'VERB'), ('group', 'NOUN'), ('.', '.')]`

This is the code that I've written

```
import pyconll
import pprint

word_tag_list = list()

conll_words_file = pyconll.load_from_file("./grc_perseus-ud-train.conllu")

for sentence in conll_words_file:
    for text in sentence:
        for word in sentence:
            word_tag_list.append(tuple((word.form, word.upos)))
print(word_tag_list)
```

As you noticed in the first example for each sentence I store a list, that is contained within another list.

This is the repository of the CONLLU file: [CONLLU REPOSITORY](https://github.com/UniversalDependencies/UD_Ancient_Greek-Perseus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you want to put each sentence in its own sublist.

You need to create each sublist inside the loop instead of appending everything directly to the outer list.

```
word_tag_list = list()

conll_words_file = pyconll.load_from_file("./grc_perseus-ud-train.conllu")

for sentence in conll_words_file:
    sentence_list = []
    for text in sentence:
        for word in sentence:
            sentence_list.append(tuple((word.form, word.upos)))
    word_tag_list.append(sentence_list)

print(word_tag_list)
```